# Better search on WordPress.org Plugins?

Tags: plugins, block-editor, wordpress.org

I'm trying to find some specific plugin for Accordion (FAQ), but to be in a form of Gutenberg Block. There is a group of "block enabled" plugins on https://wordpress.org/plugins/browse/blocks/

There should be a simple way of achieving this task. I've done a lot of experimenting, but none of the results were satisfactory enough.

#### Using specialized sites

- https://wpdirectory.net/;

  Tried searching for `(?mi)(^\s*Plugin\s+Name:.+accordion.+$)` to achieve case-insensitive search for `accordion` in plugin name. But I can't search also for "blocks" plugins as there is impossible to achieve AND functionality :(
- https://wpcore.com/plugin-directory; I tried to use their search-form, but the results are not better than on wordpress.org
- lots of unmaintained or defunct sites:

  - https://addendio.com/,
  - http://searchwpplugins.com/,
  - http://www.wpmeta.org/,
  - http://wpplugindirectory.org/

#### Using Google

I've had some results using Google queries like this one:

```
inurl:wordpress.org/plugins/browse/blocks/ accordion
```

... but that gave me only "list" and not "plugin" pages. Not satisfactory at all!

I still believe that it is somehow possible to get better results from Google

#### Experiment with Wordpress.org public API

I've found "some solution" via Wordpress.org API. Read my own answer...

Comment: Is there a better way? There MUST be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

At first, extracting results into a file with:

```sh
# create a file needed
curl --globoff --silent "https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=query_plugins&request[browse]=blocks&request[page]=1&request[per_page]=400" | jq ".plugins[] | { name: .name, url: \"https://wordpress.org/plugins/\\(.slug)/\", short: .short_description, description: .description }" > wp-block-plugins.json
curl --globoff --silent "https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=query_plugins&request[browse]=blocks&request[page]=2&request[per_page]=400" | jq ".plugins[] | { name: .name, url: \"https://wordpress.org/plugins/\\(.slug)/\", short: .short_description, description: .description }" >> wp-block-plugins.json
```

Now, when I have file `wp-block-plugins.json`, I can search for plugins I need:

```sh
# case in-sensitive search in description field for term 'accordion'
cat wp-block-plugins.json | jq '. | select(.description | test("\\baccordion\\b";"")) |{ name: .name, short: .short, url: .url }'
```

will get me desired results that look something like this, which is what I wanted in the first place:

```
...

{
  "name": "Cosmic Blocks (40+) Content Editor Blocks Collection",
  "short": "Blocks collection of 40+ customizable WordPress 5.0 gutenberg content blocks for the new content block&hellip;",
  "url": "https://wordpress.org/plugins/cosmic-blocks/"
}
{
  "name": "Hot Blocks",
  "short": "A collection of several blocks for new WordPress editor (Gutenberg).",
  "url": "https://wordpress.org/plugins/hot-blocks/"
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a proper site:

https://pluginsearch.com/

Search query that *kinda* works:

```
https://pluginsearch.com/gutenberg/?query=faq
```

Best solution so far!